# launch an event When pressing balloon of maps with api google maps v2 in Android?

Tags: android, maps

anyone know how to do it?
I found a lot of information to launch events
When pressing markers
but I did not find about of  balloons

Comment: What is a "balloon" with respect to Maps V2?

Comment: I was
searching
with the wrong word , Info Windows is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "balloons" I'm assuming Info Windows? The window that pops up when you press on a marker?

If so, you can customize your info windows using the guide below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

Scroll down to "Info window click events" to see how to add onClick events for info windows